# Ignore Terminated Exceptions in Celery Error Emails

Tags: python, django, celery

I have `CELERY_SEND_TASK_ERROR_EMAILS` enabled. I also have a task which is expected to be occasionally Terminated which when it occurs results in an error email. Is it possible that have this expected case ignored such that I don’t get the error email?

I’ve tried adding `throws=(Terminated,)` to the decorator but that doesn’t appear to have resolved the problem.

So, the decorator is as such:

```
@shared_task(default_retry_delay=10, max_retries=5, throws=(Terminated,))
```

The traceback looks like the following:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/sendhub_build/sendhub/venv/3de3b64fe072e06e8419927637fe3c948b576707/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/billiard/pool.py", line 1672, in _set_terminated
    raise Terminated(-(signum or 0))
Terminated: 15
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like this behavior has been fixed as of Celery 3.1.11:

http://celery.readthedocs.org/en/latest/changelog.html#version-3-1-11